# Setvalue of autocomplete field doesn't work

Tags: autocomplete, orbeon, xforms, formbuilder

I want to set value of autocomplete field using xf:setvalue. I know that firstly I have to set value of field and then set label (@label). I try to do that in following way:

```
<xf:setvalue ref="xxf:instance('fr-form-instance')//*[name() = $autocomplete-name]" value="'myValue'"/>
<xf:setvalue ref="xxf:instance('fr-form-instance')//*[name() = $autocomplete-name]/@label" value="'labelValue'"/>
```

After that in form builder I see, that in main instance it looks properly:

```
<xf:instance id="fr-form-instance" xxf:exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
    <form>
        <section-5>
            <control-10 label="labelValue">myValue</control-10>
        </section-5>
    </form>
</xf:instance>
```

but unfortunately in my autocomplete field there is no change. I can notice the change only if I go to 'edit source' button in form builder, and without any change, I click 'apply'. Then autocomplete is automatically refreshed and I see my label: 'labelValue'. What should I do, to refresh autocomplete field after setvalue ??

regards

Answer (score 1):

You need to do this by [setting the label of the autocomplete](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/xbl-components/autocomplete#TOC-Setting-by-label), not its value, which is done by dispatching the `fr-set-label` event to the autocomplete control. Then, internally, the autocomplete will do something very similar to what it does if the user had entered that label, in particular calling the service to retrieve the corresponding value.

Comment: Thank You. I've tried to do that: I have some action which is executing after user click on some button. Inside this action I put code from your link: <xf:dispatch ev:event="DOMActivate" target="control-10" name="fr-set-label"><xxf:context name="label" select="'White'"/></xf:dispatch> where 'control-10' is the name of my autocomplete.  Unfortunately it doesn't work: after click on my button, action is executing, but label in autocomplete is still empty

Comment: Could you create a "minimal" example that I can run here to reproduce the problem? It would need to use a public service, but you can just use a static file for that, e.g. https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/6900/resources/20131119-countries.xml. The you can post the source for your code on https://gist.github.com/ and just link to it from here.

Comment: I have 2 variables: control-name which is the name of my autocomplete, and control-value contains value which should be assign to label of autocomplete. All code is in xbl file (my own control): https://gist.github.com/pumbosha/9185683436023a43893a

Comment: Right, but could put everything that is required to run the example in a single file, so I can run it here, and see the problem you're describing?

Comment: Ok, so there is example which is created to show, how I try to setvalue of autocomplete. I writed 2 buttons which call REST service. First works perfectly. It assign result of service with simple input control. Second tries to assign result of the same service with label of autocomplete, but unfortunately it doesn't work. This is xforms example, so it will be sufficient to paste code to form builder. https://gist.github.com/pumbosha/b2a5512616bdf4aa7b3c

Comment: Maybe just a typo, but you need to dispatch the event to `control-3-control`, as this is the id of the autocomplete. Here is an example that works: https://gist.github.com/avernet/cfc7f3517c8c3627b409. Maybe working out from this one, you can figure what doesn't work in your case.

Comment: I am sorry, but I still don't know how to do it, but I think that we are getting close. I modified your example with change only URL in autocomplete and target in dispatch, and It doesn't work. I don't understand what is wrong with my xml resource in autocomplete. This is modified example: https://gist.github.com/pumbosha/b6bd44831a5470cd1b78

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get a chance to look into this one yet; I'll do my best to look at your example tomorrow.

Comment: Sorry for the wait; I still have this on my list, but have just been too busy the past few days. I should be able to follow-up on this with you next week!

Comment: OK, dont't worry. I try to fix that on my own, but currently I can't, so I will still wait for your response. Regards

Comment: Got it: I managed to reproduce the issue, and it is now fixed. The fix will be in 4.9 CE and 4.8.2 PE. And for more on this, see the following issue: https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/2098

Comment: You're welcome, and I hope this will help resolve the issue for you.